# Проблема с включением в скрипт шаблонов с одинаковыми функциями

Tags: php, require, gearman

Всем привет.
Всю голову сломал, помогите советом.
Делаю генерацию XML файлов через gearman.
В воркере есть функция которая циклом обходит названия шаблонов и вставляет их внутри функции. Проблема в том что шаблоны хоть и разные но функции у них одинаковые (т.е. названия функций одинаковые) PHP вываливает Fatal error при повторном require.

```
function regenirationXMLsFreeBoards($job){ //Запуск задачи
    ...
    foreach($FreeBoards as $Board){ //Обходим бесплатные доски
       if(!generationXMLFile($Board)) break;
    }
    ...
}
function generationXMLFile($Board){
    $dir = "../../xmls/";
    $BoardName = $Board["name"];
    $template = $dir."templates/".$BoardName.".php";
    require $template;
    createXML($fileXML); //Эта функция из шаблона $template
    ...
}
```

Т.е. первый цикл проходит успешно, на втором отваливаемся из за ошибки

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare createXML()

Шаблонов может быть много, пока только два.
Помогите советом, что можно предпринять. В голову пришло только создать отдельную функцию в расчете, что заново вызвав её потеряем предыдущий require.
Только я вот забыл что require вставляется в скрипт при первом использовании и остается на все время жизни скрипта.

Если что то не понятно, спрашивайте, я объясню.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во включаемых файлах вместо:

```
function createXML()
{
   // ....
}
```

Делайте:

```
$createObjectXML = function () {
   // что нужно
};

$createXML = function () use ($createObjectXML) {
   $var = $createObjectXML();
   // ...
};
```

Затем:

```
require $template;
$createXML($fileXML);
```

Так как это не функция, а переменная, конфликтов не будет.

Если нужно просто решить проблему, то вариант выше подойдет. Если же нужно чтобы было хорошо, то лучше будет поднять ставки в игре в абстракции, и завести отдельные именован­ные объекты с необходимыми методами под каждый отчет или что вы делаете. Всё равно эти классы и файлы будет редактировать программист.

Comment: Тоже думал об этом, но пока не имею представления как это будет работать.

Comment: Так работает. Я проверил перед тем как ответ писать.

Comment: А как теперь получать return из функции?  `Fatal error:  Function name must be a string in ... on line 738`    `738: return $result;`

Comment: Как в любой обычной функцией, только `$` в начале имени.

Comment: Почему мне тогда выводит `Fatal error: Function name must be a string in ... on line 738`?

Comment: Что там за код на этой строке? Отсюда не видно.

Comment: `$result = $createObjectXML($XMLFile);` - это в функции $createXML($fileXML); в самом начале прописал global $createObjectXML; Параллельно существует `$createObjectXML = function ($XMLFile){...}` Но почему то выдает `Fatal error: Function name must be a string in ... on line 738`

Comment: Порядок определения функций точно не перепутан? Зачем `global` здесь? Попробуйте отладить что за функцию вы вызываете: `var_dump($name);`

Comment: var_dump выдает NULL. global потому что функция передана в переменную которая объявлена выше, т.е. на уровне $createXML а не внутри функции.

Comment: Есть две функции $createXML = function(); и $createObjectXML = function(); Из функции $createXML я вызываю функцию $createObjectXML. В результате получаю Fatal error. Что не так?

Comment: Вам нужно использовать замыкание. Сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: А если несколько функций нужно? use($createObjectXML, ..., ...)? С замыкание не сталкивался еще)

Comment: Да, так `use($a, $b, $c ...)` или можно использовать `$this->...` если вы внутри объекта делали замыкание

Comment: Спасибо, сделал замыкание и все работает!)

Answer (score 1):

Варианта три (но суть одна - добиться разных "full qualified" имен для функций)

1. Поменять имена функций, чтобы они не совпадали
2. Использовать разные пространства имен
3. Провести рефакторинг и вынести эти функции в методы разных классов